# how can I color the odd numbers with blue and even numbers with red in a "Table hundred"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to add two colors to this code; red to even numbers and blue to odd...
now I tried to use some module to check which are the odds and even...but without luck..

```
<head>
    <script>
        for(var i=0;i<=9;i++)
        {
            for(var j=1;j<=10;j++)
            {
                if(i*10+j<10)
                    document.write("&nbsp"+"&nbsp");
                if((i*10+j)%7==0)
                {
                    //document.write("<b>");
                    document.write(i*10+j+"&nbsp");
                    //document.write("</b>");

                }
                else
                    document.write(i*10+j+"&nbsp");
                if(j==10)
                    document.write("<br/>");
            }
        }   
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added an answer that you might find useful going forward.

- Slightly smaller code footprint
- It doesn't have nested loops
- It doesn't rely on `document.write`. Instead it uses string concatenation to build up the HTML and then adds that string to the document. This is more efficient.
- It calls a separate function to build the span using a joined array.

JavaScript

```
var div = document.getElementById('out');
var out = '';

var getSpan = function (i) {
    return ['<span class="', (i % 2 === 0 ? 'red' : 'blue'), '">', i, '</span>'].join('');
}

for (var i = 1, l = 100; i <= l; i++) {
    if (i % 10 === 0) {
        out += getSpan(i) + '<br/>';
    } else {
        out += getSpan(i) + '&nbsp;';
        if (i <= 10) out += '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
    }
}

div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', out);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vLd9gw9L/20/)

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

JavaScript

```
for(var i=0;i<=9;i++)
{
    for(var j=1;j<=10;j++)
    {
        document.write("<span style='color:" + (Math.floor(j/2)*2 === j ? "red" : "blue") + ";'>");

        if(i*10+j<10)
            document.write("&nbsp"+"&nbsp");
        if((i*10+j)%7==0)
        {
            //document.write("<b>");
            document.write(i*10+j+"&nbsp");
            //document.write("</b>");

        }
        else
            document.write(i*10+j+"&nbsp");

        document.write("</span>");

        if(j==10)
            document.write("<br/>");
    }
}
```

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/jkz571pb/1/) fiddle.